# ModelBinder for interface for identity of model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an `IIdentifiable` interface:

```
public interface IIdentifiable
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}
```

And a simple class `Foo`:

```
public class Foo : IIdentifiable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When I have a page that needs to add a set of `Foo` and the specify one as the default, I'd have a view model like this:

```
public class BarViewModel
{
    public IList<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
    public Foo DefaultFoo { get; set; }
}
```

So in reality I'd like to *only* pass the Ids around and not the actual full objects inside hidden inputs (that's just nasty and not required). All bar cares about (int the database at least) is between a Bar and it's Foo.Ids and the default Foo.Id.

I was hoping to easily add a model binder that would be able to accept all `IIdentifiable`s and then set the Id if only an `int` is set for the value provider. The problem that I ran into is that I can't do something like the following and have it set the Id (since model binders don't look at the derived type chain...ugh):

```
ModelBinders.Binders[typeof(IIdentifiable)] = new IdentifiableModelBinder();
```

So I decided to extend the `DefaultModelProvider` to allow this capability for if the type is an `IIdentifiable` and the value found in the value provider is just a string/int, then create the model and set the `Id` property to the matching value:

```
public class DefaultWithIdentifiableModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{

    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {

        var modelType = bindingContext.ModelType;
        bool isList = false;

        // Determine the real type of the array or another generic type.
        if (modelType.IsArray)
        {
            modelType = modelType.GetElementType();
            isList = true;
        }
        else if (modelType.IsGenericType)
        {
            var genericType = modelType.GetGenericTypeDefinition();

            if (genericType == typeof(IEnumerable<>) || genericType == typeof(IList<>) || genericType == typeof(ICollection<>))
            {
                modelType = modelType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                isList = true;
            }
        }

        // The real model type isn't identifiable so use the default binder.
        if (!typeof(IIdentifiable).IsAssignableFrom(modelType))
        {
            return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
        }

        // Get the value provider for the model name.
        var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

        // Get the string values from the value provider.
        var stringValues = valueProviderResult != null ? (IEnumerable<string>)valueProviderResult.RawValue : Enumerable.Empty<string>();

        int tempFirstId = -1;

        // If the first element is an integer, we assume that only the Ids are supplied
        // and therefore we parse the list.
        // Otherwise, use the default binder.
        if (stringValues.Any() && int.TryParse(stringValues.First(), out tempFirstId))
        {

            var listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] { modelType });

            var items = (IList)base.CreateModel(controllerContext, bindingContext, listType);

            // Create each identifiable object and set the Id.
            foreach (var id in stringValues)
            {
                var item = (IIdentifiable)Activator.CreateInstance(modelType);
                item.Id = int.Parse(id);
                items.Add(item);
            }

            if (items.Count == 0)
            {
                return null;
            }

            // Determine the correct result to return.
            if (bindingContext.ModelType.IsArray)
            {
                var array = Array.CreateInstance(modelType, items.Count);
                items.CopyTo(array, 0);
                return array;
            }
            else if (isList)
            {
                return items;
            }
            else
            {
                return items[0];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
        }

    }

}
```

I'm just not sure if this is really necessary for what I'm trying to do. If anyone could leave feedback/suggestions/improvements on this type of model binding it would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**: Here's a simple example:

An order has many items, so instead of loading the whole object graph of the Item, only the Id is *really* required for use with the ORM and in the database. Therefore, the item class is loaded with the Id and then the item can be added to the list of items for the order:

```
public class Order
{
    List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

var order = new Order();
order.Items.Add(new Item() { Id=2 });
order.Items.Add(new Item() { Id=5 });
```

This is because the postback to complete the order doesn't send the *whole* `Item`, it just sends the Ids.

This is my core requirement. When a postback occurs, I need to build the Items from an Id from the postback. Regardless of if this is a view model or the actual domain model, I still need a way of easily converting from ints to the domain model with the Id set. Make sense?

Comment: Does IIdentifiable mean stored in the database?  This is unusual. Why not just pass the id as party of the request?

Comment: @jfar - The id is being passed as part of the request, but using the repository pattern, I can't just *add* an Id, I need to add the entity that has that Id. Therefore on every request, it needs to recreate the entity with that Id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a decent way but not very extensible.  If you're unlikely to have this same situation arise with different interfaces, then it's a fine solution.

An alternative would be to use reflection at startup to find all types that implement `IIdentifiable` and assign the custom model binder for all of them.

Comment: This was where I was thinking of going next because I didn't really like messing around with the default model binder. I like the idea of just reflecting over all types that implement the interface and assign the custom model binder. This way I *just* keep a `IdentifiableModelBinder`.

Comment: @TheCloudlessSky, could you explain what do you mean by "messing around with the default model binder"? Especially about why do you think it is **messing**?

Comment: @Vasilio - overriding the default model binder in my opinion isn't a good solution to this. It just feels wrong.

Comment: @TheCloudlessSky, I think that what you want is done **with** DefaultModelBinder, not by overriding it. You just want to bind simple properties on simple ViewModel - it is quite trivial and easily doable. Of course, if I understand that right. What you do with your `DefaultWithIdentifiableModelBinder` - all that is done with default one. At least in MVC3.

Comment: @Vasilio - this can not be done with the current default model binder in mvc 3. I've read the source extensively to understand it.

Comment: @TheCloudlessSky, well, maybe I misread something. Btw, could you provide more realistic scenario along with types examples? Just to see what exactly you want to achieve. If you just want to add/edit your entities that all seem very trivial. But something makes me think that there is somewhat "ID generation" task also touched by the topic. Why there is situation when you don't know the type of ID of your incoming object?

Answer (score 3):

I have experienced similar problem as following solution.

Firstly, create your interface. It's name is *IInterface* in following example.

After that, create your *CustomBinderProvider* like below;

```
public class IInterfaceBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
       public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
       {
           if (context.Metadata.ModelType.GetInterface(nameof(IInterface)) != null)
           {
               return new BinderTypeModelBinder(typeof(IInterface));
           }

           return null;
       }
}
```

Now, you can implement your binder as follows;

```
public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
{
           // Do something

           var model = (IInterface)Activator.CreateInstance(bindingContext.ModelType);

           // Do something

           bindingContext.Model = model;
           bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(bindingContext.Model);
           return Task.FromResult(model);
}
```

Finally, you have to insert your provider to **Startup** class as follows;

```
services.AddMvcCore(x =>
{
     x.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new IInterfaceBinderProvider());
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, lets suppose you need `Foo` and its data somewhere. Therefore you save the `Name` for it (maybe along with other properties) and retrieve all that data from persistence as a `Foo` instance and this is exactly **what your domain entity for**. It contains all the data related to `Foo`.

On the other side you have a View where the only thing you want operate with is `Id` so you create the ViewModel which contains the `Id` as property (and maybe more Ids like `ParentFooId` for example) and this is **what your ViewModel for**. It contains only data specific to your View - its like an interface between your View and Controller.

That way everything is done with `DefaultModelBinder`. For example, if you have:

- an `id` (of type `int`) parameter in your RouteData dictionary or have it posted via form;
- `BarViewModel` instance as a parameter of your controller's Action;
- `Id` property of `BarViewModel`

then on request the value of that `barViewModel.Id` property will be the value from your RouteData (or your form) because `DefaultModelBinder` is capable of that. And you only create custom `IModelBinder` for really unusual scenario.

I just don't see a reason to overcomplicate things.

Makes sense?

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I think I am slightly over complicating things. The ViewModel could pertain a list of `int`s and then I could easily use AutoMapper to map these back to the domain model for easy adding to the repository/use with the services.

Comment: Well, actually you don't have to. AutoMapper does its work perfectly by transforming from **Domain Entity** to **ViewModels**. DefaultModelBinder from the other side easily binds everything nicely without AutoMapper being involved. If you have a parameter of type, say `FooViewModel`, all those properties will be bound by name from Route values and POST-ed form. That way they also be automatically validated during binding (if have any DataAnnotations).

Comment: @Vasilio - Yes, but I'd need AutoMapper to map back from the `FooViewModel` to the actual Domain Entity used in the repository.

Comment: You don't *NEED* automapper do map back to domain models.  In fact I wouldn't do it at all.  Changing your models should be considered a sacrosanct act and not appropriate for any automated tool.

Comment: @TheCloudlessSky, Like jfar said you don't need. When its good in Entity->WiewModel scenario. But not otherwise. You actually **can** but I don't recommend that. I'd prefer more control and explicity when creating entities.

Comment: Ok, but this isn't the *creation* of the models. This is strictly instantiating a model type with an id.

Comment: @TheCloudlessSky - Whats wrong with SomeRepository.Load(int someId ) inside your controller?

Comment: @jfar - A lot since all I want is to load the entity with the id and that's not a responsibility for the repository. All that I need is a simple method to create objects of the entity type with the id set for using this.

Comment: @TheCloudlessSky, what do you mean by "load the entity with the id and that's not a responsibility for the repository"? I always thought it **is** the responsibility of repository to load entity.